# Create my own tutorial in wxpython application

Tags: python, wxpython

I have created my own wxpython application and compiled it with PyInstaller.  I have a tutorial (simply a notepad file) that I include with the application.  My python code simply just opens the file (os.startfile) and the user can read it.  However, I would like to build my own sort of tutorial/troubleshooting guide seen in most applications.  Is there a template for this or wxpython dialog that I'm missing?

When I try to google this, all I get are wxpython tutorials themselves (no help).

I would like to be able to have an indexed tutorial, search ability, and troubleshooting guide.

Any help/direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The closer widget I know in wx is the wizard dialog  [wx.wizard](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.wizard.Wizard-class.html).
You have a tutorial [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/27/wxpython-a-wizard-tutorial/)

It has not searching facilities, etc but probably you could add them programmatically